# How to downgrade to previous versions of Mono with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I recently bought a vps running Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the latest stable version of mono (5.20.1) via the official website. I also needed to downgrade to a previous version between 4.0 to 4.2 for compability matters.

I followed the official guide but it didnt work https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases

I also tried to edit my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list` and change:

`deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main`

to

`deb [trusted=yes] http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic/snapshots/4.2.0 main`

Everything works fine when I use the `sudo apt update` but once I use the `sudo apt install mono-complete` and run `mono --version`, it still shows the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list`, then do:

```
sudo apt purge mono-devel mono-complete
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-devel mono-complete
```

This way you will consume the mono packages bundled by Ubuntu (not Microsoft), which brings mono version 4.2.6 (or 4.6.2, not sure). If you depend on even an older version than this, you're... ahem... in a bad position.